# No results for match...against in boolean mode search with fulltext index (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

We have a column with a fulltext index, and are matching 'asp.net' against the column in boolean mode. We know there are records where this column contains the value 'asp.net', but the query is returning no records.

We have not modified any MySQL configuration directives pertaining to fulltext indexes. I believe the default minimum word length for fulltext indexes is 3 or 4 (certainly less than 7), so this query should still return at least one record.

Is there something else we're missing? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up asking a DBA, and he said that the comma is recognized as a word separator in MySQL. So, that meant that it was looking for "asp" and "net", both of which are under the 4 character minimum for words to be included in a fulltext index. I added the configuration directive `ft_min_word_len=3` to `my.cnf`, restarted mysqld, and rebuilt the fulltext index on the table. Using `MATCH(column-name) AGAINST ('+asp +net' IN BOOLEAN MODE);` now locates the proper records.

Thanks everyone for your help!